# unable to unpack php array with $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an array stored in php: `$cv1 = array('a','b');`

As you can see in the code below, I am trying to get the respective data from the array then delegate it to two separate functions.

But the data returned from the php callback function is: 'Array' instead of 'a','b';
and result[0] gets 'A' result[1] gets 'r' etc.

Thanks for help!

js:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
  var cv = $(this).data('cv');
  var url= '_php/myphp.php';
  $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data) {
    result=data;
    return result;
  }).done(function() {
    alert(result[0]);
    $('#myDiv').html(result[1]);
  });
});
```

php:

```
$cv1 = array("a","b");

$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];

if($contentVar == "cv1")
{
    echo json_encode($cv1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common in PHP for you to get `"Array"` instead of an actual array when it accidentally gets cast to a string. That's not what you're doing here though; we can test:

```
> $cv1 = array("a","b");
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "a"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "b"
}
> json_encode($cv1);
string(9) "["a","b"]"
```

`$cv1` gets encoded correctly.

You must be treating it like a string somewhere else:

```
> (string)array("a","b")
! Array to string conversion
string(5) "Array"
```

Also, why do you have two success callbacks in `$.post`? The 3rd argument is a success callback, which works the same as `.done`. Use one or the other (I recommend `done`) but not both.

You may also consider passing `json` as the last argument (dataType) so that jQuery knows what to expect and will properly decode the result.

Comment: Thanks! passing the `json` argument does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
$.post(url,{contentVar:cv}
   function(response)
   {
      alert(response[0]);
   },'json'
);
```

Comment: You need to indicate which data type "in this case json" you will use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the json string format to a javascript object/array.

> var result = $.parseJSON(data);

see this question [jQuery ajax request with json response, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098649/jquery-ajax-request-with-json-response-how-to/9099182#9099182) for more detail.

But there is something strange that, if is returning 'Array', the php is not converting the array to json, what happens if the `($contentVar == "cv1")` return false? If you will return an array to javascript you need to convert to a string (and the json format is perfect for this).