# How to access data from JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pha0.png
This is the part of my JSON. I need to access `photo_file_url`

I tried to write it as

```
$.ajax( {
        url: "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=1&minx="+longitude+"&miny="+latitude+"&maxx="+lonmax+"&maxy="+latmax+"&size=original&mapfilter=true",
        type: "get",
        success: function(response) {
        document.getElementById("back").innerHTML = response.photos.photo_file_url;
        }
});
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: is `photos` an array/list of photo objects? If so you need to access those via their index first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing an async GET request, you can also use

```
$.getJSON("http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=1&minx="+longitude+"&miny="+latitude+"&maxx="+lonmax+"&maxy="+latmax+"&size=original&mapfilter=true", function(response) {
  // response will be a json object
  document.getElementById("back").innerHTML = response.photos.photo_file_url;
});
```

I recommend this solution **only** because you are doing an asynchronous GET request which is synonymous with `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax( {
        url: "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&from=0&to=1&minx="+longitude+"&miny="+latitude+"&maxx="+lonmax+"&maxy="+latmax+"&size=original&mapfilter=true",
        type: "get",
        success: function(response) {
        response = $.parseJson(response); //parse json object
        document.getElementById("back").innerHTML = response.photos.photo_file_url;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response) {
    document.getElementById("back").innerHTML = JSON.parse(response).photos[0].photo_file_url;
}
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json"
    succes: ...
```

Or [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax-Parse JS/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

[How to access JSON object in JavaScript](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/)

I don't know how helpful these will be but hopefully it's a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Your response is a string, you can convert it to an object using `JSON.parse`.

EDIT: For compatibaility `$.parseJSON`. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098649/jquery-ajax-request-with-json-response-how-to).