# Manage sessions with jQuery/HTML in the frontend and PHP/MySQL in the backend

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like to build a site that has only HTML/jQuery in the frontend and PHP/MySQL in the backend.

How can I manage the user sessions (login/logout) and work with session variables using only HTML/jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: There are frameworks that can help me?

Comment: even if you want you can not have php at front-end also you can not manage session at client side because session stays at server side

you can send ajax request via javascript/jQuery and logout user

Comment: you can do this with angular

Comment: How do you intend to get data from the backend to the frontend without using PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how create a session using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257631/how-create-a-session-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could perform AJAX calls to a page in php with method to login, logout and query for session variables.

Also. If your app is not working with server at regultar intervals make request to server to keep session alive.

Login example

JQuery

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://yoursite.com/ajax.php?method=login",
  data: yourloginData,
  success: yourSuccesAction
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['method']){
    if ($_GET['method'] == 'login'){
      // do login here and print response to server 
      // for example in json with json_encode
    }
}
```

More information see:

[Demo: jQuery Ajax Call to PHP Script with JSON Return](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/)

[jQuery ajax request with json response, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098649/jquery-ajax-request-with-json-response-how-to)