# Responce back after create charge in Stripe

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have below code in Ruby file which is

```
post '/create_charge' do
  # Create the charge on Stripe's servers
  begin
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => params[:amount], # this number should be in cents
      :currency => "usd",
      :source => params[:source],
      :description => "sample"
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return log_info("Error creating charge: #{e.message}")
  end

  status 200
  return log_info("Charge successfully created")
end
```

and my question is how to pass json value after creating successfully  charge.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: did you try .to_json or .as_json on charge ? otherwise try JSON.parse(charge.data)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return json response of the charge request, you can pass charge into body of response:

```
post '/create_charge' do
  # Create the charge on Stripe's servers
  charge = {}
  begin
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => params[:amount], # this number should be in cents
      :currency => "usd",
      :source => params[:source],
      :description => "sample"
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    status 402
    return log_info("Error creating charge: #{e.message}")
  end

  status 200
  content_type :json
  body charge.to_json   
  return log_info("Charge successfully created")
end
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your responce Can you please tell me how we should handle in JS file :)

Comment: Okay, if you are using jQuery u can use $.post( "endpoint",{ },
    function(data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       console.log(response)
    }
)

Comment: also you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098649/jquery-ajax-request-with-json-response-how-to

Comment: Thanks but my responce is coming null Also i deployed my stripe charge code is in heroku.

Comment: Can you please check in browser network tab if its returning data in response?

Comment: 'not found' but in stripe i can see charges service got 200 responce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173224/discussion-between-userar-and-shan-kulkarni).